# Looking for a way to remove repetitive answers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to write a code that detects collision of 100 random circles on the surface in range of -15<=x,y<=15. Code works well but there is one problem which happens to be repetitive reverse answers for example program gives me results like:

```
disc 1 with disc 85
disc 8 with disc 35
...................
disc 35 with disc 8
...................
disc 85 with disc 1
...................
```

So it will show only 1 and 85 not reversed 85 and 1.
I'm trying to figure out how to remove them because I need it for the next part of my code.

```
import math    
lista=[[],[],[]]  
import random

for i in range(0,100):  
    lista[0].append(random.uniform(-14.5,14.5))  
    lista[1].append(random.uniform(-14.5,14.5))  
    lista[2].append(0.5)

def kol(a):  
    for i in range(0,100):  
        q1=lista[0][i]  
        w1=lista[1][i]  
        for k in range(0,100):  
            if k==i:  
                continue  
            q2=lista[0][k]  
            w2=lista[1][k]  
            if math.sqrt((abs(q1-q2))**2+(abs(w1-w2))**2)<1:                     
                  print('Kolizja dysków: ',i+1,'z',k+1)

print(kol(1))
```

Comment: note that `if math.sqrt((abs(q1-q2))**2+(abs(w1-w2))**2)<1:` can be `if ((abs(q1-q2))**2+(abs(w1-w2))**2)<1:  `

Comment: you've got a redundancy here: `for k in range(i+1,100):` would be better

Answer (score 1):

your loop checks the distances twice, since you're only excluding the same index, not the upper or lower triangle, which explains the repeats.

I'd rewrite it as is:

```
for i in range(0,100):  
    q1=lista[0][i]  
    w1=lista[1][i]  
    for k in range(i+1,100): # only above i  
        q2=lista[0][k]  
        w2=lista[1][k]  
        if ((abs(q1-q2))**2+(abs(w1-w2))**2)<1:                     
              print('Kolizja dysków: ',i+1,'z',k+1)
```

Aside, don't test square root, because square value < 1 is equivalent to value < 1, so save some computing power.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for k in range(0,100):
```

use

```
for k in range(i + 1, 100):
```

so that `k` is always greater than `i`.